# Lebesgue measure of a line using polar coordinates

Tags: measure-theory, euclidean-geometry

A line can be parametrized in multiple ways:

1. slope and intercept.
2. polar coordinates: perpendicular distance $p$ from the origin, and angle $\theta$.

[image: polar coordinates]

(among others, of course, but these are the ones I'm interested in).

One can define a measure on lines parametrized in these different ways. These are

1. a measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$
2. a measure on $[0,2\pi] \times \mathbb{R}$.

How does the lebesgue product measure compare in these two cases? I read (while reading about the [Cauchy-Crofton formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofton_formula)) that the product of lebesgue measures on $[0,2\pi]$ and $\mathbb{R}$ gives a measure on lines that is invariant under rigid motions. Is this also true or the product lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$? Would we just use the usual polar-rectangular transformation to transform between these measures?

Comment: Slope and intercept are not sufficient to describe all lines, as vertical lines have infinite slope and no $y$-intercept.

Comment: @PaulSinclair that's true. but I'm wondering about measures on lines and so those would have measure 0 anyways